# How to prove that if $MM^TU=U\Sigma^2$ and $M^TMV=V\Sigma^2$ then $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, svd

In the context of Singular Value Decomposition. Suppose $U$ and $V$ are invertible. How to prove that if $$MM^TU=U\Sigma^2$$ and $$M^TMV=V\Sigma^2$$

then $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal?

In the context of singular value decomposition, ($\Sigma$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues of M )

Comment: This is not algebraic-geometry. Please read tags a little more carefully before applying them to your question.

Comment: You probably forgot some of the conditions, because we could have  $U=V=0$ and then it wouldn't work... Maybe you assumed that  $U $ and  $V $ invertible ?

Comment: @Paul I edited the question, thanks. We have to assume that U and V are invertible.

Comment: @KReiser The tag was already changed, thanks for noticing

Comment: @JuanMuñoz yes, I was the one who changed it. Please keep in mind when you ask questions in the future that selecting appropriate tags is also part of asking a good question.

Comment: @KReiser Sure. Do you have any clue about my question?